# Protocol Buffer: Version Change

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have accidentally installed version 3.0.0 and most of my files naturally gave tons of errors. Now I want to take it back to 2.6.1. I already downloaded 2.6.1 and installed, however when I do `protoc --version` it still shows `libprotoc 3.0.0`, which is wrong.

Is there a way to set the version to 2.6.1 or is there a way to uninstall 3.0.0?

Comment: What platform? How did you install (package manager, from source)? What does `which protoc` point to?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. I installed it from source. And that command points to `/usr/local/bin/protoc`

Comment: Are you sure you used the same install prefix for both versions? It's possible you have both installed (one in `/usr` and one in `/usr/local` for example).

Comment: In case if I want to use the newer one, how should I switch to it?

Comment: Use the full path to the one you want, or adjust your PATH variable, or set up an alias, or delete the executable you don't want. It installs a bunch of headers and docs but you can ignore those if you want. Package managers are good because they take care of all the crap that gets installed, and can remove it all too.

Comment: I do not know which one is which, that's the problem. I have two of them installed but you can't understand from the folder name. I have something under `/local`, and some other under `/include`, and I do not know which one I should delete. I want to get rid of the previous one no matter what, and it is unbelievable that there is no straightforward way to uninstall the facility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. One should delete everything regarding google protocol buffers under `/local` and `/include`, , and then simple reinstall the other version. After that `protoc --version` shows the new version.

Comment: Hope it helps someone: I just installed proto3(3.5.1) based on https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/README.md.  I have version 2.6 installed previously.  After the installation, protoc -- version still shows 2.6.  After I restart the system, it shows 3.5.1.

Comment: Can confirm! I restarted and it worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pip:

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip install protobuf==2.6.1
```