# How can I uninstall protobuf 3.0.0?

Tags: protocol-buffers, uninstallation

I used the instructions from here to install Protocol Buffer: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md
and ended up with version 3 (`"protoc --version" "libprotoc 3.0.0"`)

However, I need a protoc version 2.

I tried to uninstall it with `apt-get remove protobuf-compiler`

But this is what I get and version 3 is still installed:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'protobuf-compiler' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 396 not to upgrade.
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and "which protoc" command points at "/usr/bin/protoc"

I am looking to an alternative solution than given in [Protocol Buffer: Version Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866772/protocol-buffer-version-change)

I am not sure if I am using the correct command for uninstalling. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I managed to uninstall protoc 3.0.0 (I am posting the answer in a beginner manner, the way I needed it explained to understand):

1) The `remove` command does not work, because the instructions I followed on protocol buffer page uses make to build the tool - you only use `remove` when installing with apt-get

2) To remove all libraries built with `make`, go to the folder where the protoc files were downloaded and run `make uninstall`. That worked. However, when I checked again with `protoc --version`, I still got `libprotoc 3.0.0`. I think the reason is because I followed one of he instructions to change the path of the installation (`./configure --prefix=/usr`) and therefore I needed to use `` rm `which protoc` `` to manually delete the leftovers from protoc 3, because the `make uninstall` was not pointing to it. After that, protoc was completely gone.

3) I installed the version I needed (any protoc 2) with `apt-get install protobuf-compiler` and now I have `libprotoc 2.5.0`

Please feel free to comment further.

Comment: `make uninstall` should have removed `protoc`, but if you had re-run `./configure` with a different `--prefix` first, then it would have removed from the wrong place. As long as you ran `./configure` with the same `--prefix` (and other flags) as when you originally installed, `make uninstall` should remove all the files (unless there's a bug!).

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I also thought my problem might have come from the different `--prefix`. However this other `--prefix` was suggested in the guidance notes and I was surprised the unistall was not as straightforward as I expected.

Comment: OMG. I used rm `which protoc` and then I cannot reinstall my prototoc.

Comment: @user8264 why not?

Comment: As of August 2017, 'conda uninstall protobuf' does NOT seem to actually remove the libs, includes, etc. from my environment. I removed the protoc binary, libs, and includes manually, and I was able to make my build process *finally* see the system protobuf (protip: if you forget to remove the include dir from your conda env you end up with cryptic errors about protobuf error mismatches).

Answer (score 6):

I have used the command `sudo apt-get remove protobuf-compiler` and reference is [How to remove protobuf-compiler from Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/protobuf-compiler?action=remove). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

If you have *Anaconda* installed on *Ubuntu*, then use:

```
conda uninstall protobuf
```

After executing the above command, try:

```
protoc --version
```

The following output confirms the successful removal of `protobuf`:

> The program 'protoc' is currently not installed. You can install it by
>   typing: sudo apt install protobuf-compiler

In case you want to install the Google Protocol Buffer, watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAFK-tN_yaw

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue and the problem was in `usr/local/include/`. It installs its header files while you were installing protoc from the source and when you uninstall it, it does not erase its include headers. Therefore, *.pb.cc files still try to include those files. I fixed the problem by removing protobuf header in `usr/local/include/` and then reinstalling libprotobuf from apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 29 `sudo dnf remove protobuf` removed my previously installed `sudo dnf -y install protoc` 3.5.0 version.

```
[dzintars@fedora ~]$ protoc
bash: protoc: command not found...
```